# Is any international (ie. non-U.S.A.) foreign financial securities market tax free or significantly less taxed than USA markets?

Tags: taxes, trading, stock-markets, foreign-exchange, international

Hypothetically, is it possible to buy and sell some kind of financial security (ie. stocks, currency, even crypto) in some foreign market and keep the money there and pay no taxes as high as short-term cap gains in United States?

Comment: what is your United sates tax status?

Comment: If you are a US citizen, all gains worldwide are taxed, even if you are not resident in the US. So at your personal level, no. The only option is to set up a company (or other form of entity which is an independent legal person) in another country, but taxation rules can become very complex, not to mention the direct and indirect costs of setting up and running the company.

Comment: mhoran:  married filing joint